# Duplicate multiple MySql rows

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, activerecord, copy, row

I'm dublicating rows in mysql-table `mytable` and updating the `profiles_id`-column a bit.
There is quite many rows that need to be dublicated and updated.

**Sometimes** I get a MYSQL-Error: `TMP table already exists` and *I can't figure out why or even recreate the error* on command. Ideas? Improvments?

*(I'm running CodeIgniter's Active Record the following)*

```
    $where = '';

    foreach($vars as $var) { 

       $where .= "id = '$var->id' OR ";
    }

    $where = substr($where , 0, -4);

    $this->db->query("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp SELECT * from mytable WHERE ( " . $where . " ) && users_id = '$user_id';");
    $this->db->query("ALTER TABLE tmp drop id;");
    $this->db->query("UPDATE tmp SET profiles_id = '$profile_id';");
    $this->db->query("INSERT INTO mytable SELECT 0,tmp.* FROM tmp; ");
    $this->db->query("DROP TABLE tmp;");
```

Comment: Added: `$this->db->query("DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tmp;");`

before the first query. Maybe this helps?

Comment: What happens if multiple users run the command at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right, I figured it out. When the queries is sent and an error occurs the last query `DROP TABLE tmp` isn't executed. There for this temporary table sticks around until the DB-connected is disconnected.

```
    $this->db->query("DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tmp;");
    $this->db->query("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp SELECT * from mytable WHERE ( " . $where . " ) && users_id = '$user_id';");
    $this->db->query("ALTER TABLE tmp drop id;");
    $this->db->query("UPDATE tmp SET profiles_id = '$profile_id';");
    $this->db->query("INSERT INTO mytable SELECT 0,tmp.* FROM tmp; ");
    $this->db->query("DROP TABLE tmp;");
```

So by adding the `DROP IF EXISTS` at the beginning this is solved.